# ¿Cómo enviar varios datos en un input con HTML y PHP?

Tags: php, html

Básicamente lo que quiero es enviar varios datos en un solo array, asumo que es mediante un array pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Coloco un ejemplo, en Gmail, en un solo input (el de correo de destinatarios) se pueden colocar varias direcciones de correo y cada una se maneja de forma individual,
Esto es lo que quiero lograr.alguien me explica cómo hacerlo o me facilita un tutorial, recomienda un framework o algo así

Comment: La tarea es muy simple no veo para que un framework, por otro lado no expones algún avance y solo una petición por lo cual tu pregunta quedará cerrada, lee [ask]

Comment: Por favor, sigue la recomendación que te comparte BetaM. Adicional, si recién empiezas puedes guiarte usando la librería PHPMailer, si tienes un avance, regresa acá y haz clic en [edit] para añadir más información, pues tu pregunta está incompleta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas **no es un framework ni nada muy elaborado**, simplemente se trata de, una vez recibido el valor del input en PHP:

- separarlo por espacios
- convertir eso a un array.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

$input = $_POST['input'];
$array = array_filter(preg_split('/\s/', $input));
```

Comment: En estos casos es mejor esperar a que el OP muestre que lleva, ya que al momento solo es seguro que su pregunta quede cerrada

Comment: @BetaM Ok, pero ¿mi respuesta no soluciona el problema que el OP estaba consultando?

Comment: Eso solo lo puede determinar el, mi recomendación va por qué el OP debe mejorar el formato de su duda exponiendo que ha hecho

Comment: Muchas, muchísimas gracias, Muc justamente es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: BetaM, no coloqué código o avance debido a que consideré que mi pregunta fué clara, además del ejemplo que ofrecí, @Muc acertó, en todo caso gracias por tu colaboración también y tendré en cuenta tu observación a futuras consultas. :)

Comment: @AlexDelaHoz buenísimo que te haya servido! Si tienes dudas puedes consultarme :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas estimado ve lo siguiente si deseas enviar varios datos desde un html debes definir un formulario que las entradas de cada input debes definirla de manera array ejemplo:

```
<form action="getter.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <p>
    Selecciona categorías:<br>
    <select multiple name="categorias[]">
      <option value="arte">Arte y entretenimiento</option>
      <option value="tv">Televisión y películas</option>
      <option value="ninos">Niños y adolescentes</option>
      <option value="hazlotu">Hazlo tu mismo</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar información"></p>
</form>
```

En la parte de PHP

```
var_dump($_POST['categorias']);
```

El apartado anterior te va a mostrar un mensaje similar a este

```
categorias" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "arte"
    1 => "tv"
    2 => "ninos"
    3 => "hazlotu"
  ]
```

Si quieres hacer envio por GET que no te recomiendo iria de esta forma el request
"body"=>"categorias%5B%5D=arte&categorias%5B%5D=tv&categorias%5B%5D=ninos&categorias%5B%5D=hazlotu"

Espero que te sea útil.